# Select statement throwing null exception

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Getting a mysterious `null exception` in second Select statement.

```
public static string GetSNFromDeviceMacAddress(string macAddress)
{
    string commzSerialNumber = null;
    var dbFactory = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();
    try
    {
        OrmDataLib.Device device;
        OrmDataLib.Commz commz;
        using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            // first select works fine
            device = db
                .Select<OrmDataLib.Device>(q => q.MacAddress == macAddress)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (null != device)
            {
                // mysterious null exception
                commz = db
                    .Select<OrmDataLib.Commz>(c => c.Id == device.Commz_Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                if (null != commz)
                    commzSerialNumber = commz.SerialNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return commzSerialNumber;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice have the OpenDbConnection code,and also which livestyle has

Comment: You need to use the lock statement.

Comment: Do you *really* have an empty catch block? Kill it!

Comment: I'm afraid I simply don't believe that the code you've given will make `db` `null`. It's a local variable which isn't changed or used in an `out` parameter during the call. How are you diagnosing that it's `null`? And why are you using `if (null != xxx)` style checks, out of interest?

Comment: I'm dubious of this line:
           device = db
                .Select<OrmDataLib.Device>(q => q.MacAddress == macAddress)
Do you intend to select the values where the macaddress comparison is true? if so, use Where, not Select.
                .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @FelicePollano Line 85 of [OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs#L85) for the `OpenDbConnection()`

Comment: What makes you think `db` is `null`? I personally very much doubt that it is. What debugging steps make you believe that? and "I got a `NullReferenceException`" is not sufficient: there are *many* things that could cause that. I would readily believe you're getting an error, sure - but I *do not* believe that `db` has become `null`.

Comment: @AlexMendez what makes you think that? in particular, this is a local variable, which therefore (since `db` is not captured into any closures) **cannot** be at risk from any other threads.

Comment: @MarcGravell It was the "I got a..." but your right, I'm in deep in the Select() code and finding its throwing in there.

Comment: @JonSkeet the `null !=` is a remnant of the days when checking for null in c or c++ would allow the null to be assigned in an if such as `(value = null)` instead of `(value == null)` typo.  Also seeing the value I'm checking for at the start is easier than at the end of a long expression.  It is messy with greater/lesser than expressions, so I revert in those cases.

Comment: @ChuckSavage k; that changes the nature of the question (I suspect you should rephrase the question, actually). The `.StackTrace` of the exception would be really useful, as would any `.InnerException`

Comment: @MarcGravell I debated that - I figured it out from your first comment and dove into the ServiceStack code to end up finding it was trying to put null into a DTO `int` variable, that should have been declared `int?`  Wish I could just delete this, but I'll make an answer and check it as the answer in a couple days (when it lets me).

Comment: @VisualMelon It is a database extension method that requires the Select(), see their [Querying with SELECT](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-with-select) docs.

Comment: @ChuckSavage thanks, that was confusing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the receiving DTO was supposed to permit a null value and wasn't.

The property,

`Commz.Site_id` was declared:

```
public int Site_id { get; set; }
```

And should have been declared as:

```
public int? Site_id { get; set; }
```